Fail to change the stacked bar chart style by openpyxl. How to fix it?
Current Style

Target Style

When I generate a percentage stacked bar chart by openpyxl, I would like it as the target style in the image attached. But what I got is the current one. The code is as below. I tried change the chart.style number. It doesn't work. Environment: Window 10 + Python 3.10 (VS 2017) + Excel 365
def chart_add_A(filename):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename)
    worksheet = workbook['A']
    
    chart_data = Reference(worksheet, min_row = 2, max_row = worksheet.max_row, min_col = 2, max_col = 3)
    chart_series = Reference(worksheet, min_row = 2, max_row = worksheet.max_row, min_col = 1, max_col = 1)
    chart_A = BarChart()
    chart_A.type = 'col'
    chart_A.style = 3
    chart_A.grouping = "percentStacked"
    chart_A.title = 'A'
    chart_A.x_axis.title = 'Month'
    chart_A.y_axis.title = 'Count'
    chart_A.legend = None
    chart_A.dLbls=label.DataLabelList()
    chart_A.dLbls.showVal=True
    chart_A.showVal = True
    chart_A.width = 24
    chart_A.height = 12
    chart_A.add_data(chart_data)
    chart_A.set_categories(chart_series)
    worksheet.add_chart(chart_A, 'A0')
    workbook.save(filename)

How can I get the target style to save the chart in excel? Thanks

I think you are just missing chart_A.overlap = 100 Mentioned in the Openpyxl Docs When using stacked charts the overlap needs to be set to 100.

Referenced in the Openpyxl documentation, Stacked Bar Charts should have their overlap set to 100.
Need to add the following setting;
chart_A.overlap = 100

